# Spring JndiTemplate and parameterized JNDI lookup from context

Tags: java, spring, jndi

How can I represent `new JndiTemplate(properties).lookup(name)`, where name is a string variable, in the Spring application context file?  Can I express it in a way similar to the following, where the application provides `name` when it retrieves the bean ID?

```
<util:properties id="applicationProperties"
    location="classpath:application.properties"/>

<jee:jndi-lookup id="connectionFactory"
    jndi-name="${name}"
    environment-ref="applicationProperties"
    resource-ref="false" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, you need something like this:

```
<bean id = "jndiTemplate" class = "org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
    <property name = "environment" ref = "applicationProperties" />
</bean>

<bean id = "objectFromJndi" factory-bean = "jndiTemplate" factory-method = "lookup"
    scope = "prototype" />
```

-

```
ApplicationContext ctx = ...;
Object o = ctx.getBean("objectFromJndi", name);
```

This will work because `getBean` can pass arguments to `factory-method`.

Comment: ah if that's the case, I may have misunderstood the question. I seem to recall there's also support for grabbing properties of other classes and using them as variables in spring 3.